# Why is my reversed linked list returning null value?

Tags: javascript, linked-list

This is my answer for leetcode number 234, it is practically word for word the same as every js answer i've found. But It says that my reversed slow node has no value, why is that? Im failing to see where the issue lies.

```
var isPalindrome = function(head) {
    
    let fast = head;
    let slow = head;
    
    while(fast !== null && fast.next.next !==null){
        fast = fast.next.next;
        slow = slow.next;
    }
    
    fast = head;
    slow = reverse(slow);
    
    while(slow !== null){
        if(fast.val !== slow.val){
            return false;
        }
        fast = fast.next;
        slow = slow.next;
    }
    
    return true;
    
};

let reverse = function(head){
    let prev = null;

    while(head !== null){
        let temp = head.next;
        head.next = prev;
        prev = head;
        head = temp;
    }

    return prev
}
```

Comment: What is your question? And,  how can this be tested, and what would your expected output be.

Comment: putting the code into https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-linked-list/ should result in true.

here is an example https://terriblewhiteboard.com/palindrome-linkedlist-leetcode-234/ of a valid answer that works if pasted into the editor. I fail to see the difference between mine and this answer.

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE, no idea what you are referring to. `prev` is local. (Also it makes no sense to mix `window` and `globalThis`. `window` is specific for browser agents.) And why you formatted your comment as code?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you debugged your problem in console, before submitting the code.

If it is not then let me tell you there is a minor bug in your code while traversing the `ListNode` by two pointers.

You are checking the `i-th` node and `i+2-th` node where you need to check `i-th` node and `i+1-th` node, remove `fast.next.next` while traversing the nodes.

```
 while(fast !== null && fast.next!==null){
    fast = fast.next.next;
    slow = slow.next;
}
```

Rest of the things is well and need to work.